# Core Data malfunctioning

Tags: objective-c, core-data

This is a strange problem im getting every now and then.
Im parsing a JSON and storing it into CoreData using several Entities. I save the data from the JSON and then I pull it to show it on a screen. 
The app works perfectly fine when it's launched from XCode, always. But when I open it any other time from the iPhone it sometimes, it only happens roughly once every 20 times, it doesnt show the data saved from the JSON, I beleive the problem is that the info saved in CoreData is corrupted some how, the dates specifically, sometimes I can get to see that the dates are null on screen.

Here's how I save the dates

```
[event setValue:[df dateFromString:(NSString *)[key objectForKey:@"startSaleDate"]] forKey:@"dateStartSale"];
[event setValue:[df dateFromString:(NSString *)[key objectForKey:@"finishSaleDate"]] forKey:@"dateEndSale"];
```

If I relauch the app, that is killing the app and launching it again, it all works perfectly again.
The JSON is always correct, apparently it does the funky thing after some hours being installed in the phone. Does that make sense?

Thanks.

[UPDATE]

I did some more testing. This is a difficult bug to catch because it only happens after several hours in the background.
Figure out that the only problem is actually storing NSDates. Not the rest of data. After some time in the background it fails to save the NSDate, even though the JSON has a valid Date it stores null.  And everytime I refresh it keeps on storing null.
If I kill and launch the app it stores correctly the date.
I tried using models but it happens the same thing.

Any ideas? Im quite lost now.

Comment: Im only using the main thread

Comment: Is your app being killed in the background without a core data save happening? You should save context whenever your app is sent to the background.

Comment: Right after I receive and parse the JSON I save the context and only then. That's the only time I actually modify the CoreData Model, should I save the context anyway in applicationDidEnterBackground? Thanks

Comment: Also when the dates become null, I refresh so it download the JSON again and it stores it again and still the dates are still null, so it's like when CoreData fails it fails until I relaunch the app.

Comment: Im not using a Model file for each entity, could that become an issue?

Comment: Is this a static JSON file, or are you pulling it from a server?

Comment: pulling it from a server

Comment: Add unit tests - test saving data and then restoring them. Compare the differences. That should help you to find the root cause of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had such an issue once I believe. In my case it had something to do with the display mechanism.

--> Try reloading your data more frequently (or resetting your fetched results controller) to test this.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys, It was all a silly mistake from my part.
I thought it was something related to the background because I wasnt able to reproduce it, and since it only happened every now and then.
Well the thing is that I if you went through the screens in a certain way a following a certain order a NSDateFormatter got badly initialised and that made that the dates weren't saved properly.

SO nothing to do with CoreData...

Comment: You might consider to delete the question.